# Access args[0] value in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to do a chaning Job.

So to some point I want to access the args (`public static void main(String[] args)`).

say args[0] in mapper.

Is there a way to access those values in mapper rather than sending them to function and accessing?
**Alternative Solution**

```
conf.set("args", args[1]);
job1.setJarByClass(BinningDriver.class);
FileSystem fs1 = FileSystem.get(conf);
job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job1.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job1.setMapperClass(BinningInput.class);
job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
Path out = new Path(args[1]+"/Indexing"); //Output goes to user output location/indexing
if(fs1.exists(out)){
    fs1.delete(out,true);
}

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, out);
}
```

Mapper

```
public void setup(Context context){
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
String param = conf.get("args");
System.out.println("args:"+param);
    }
```

This Works

Comment: What is args[0]? are you referring to `public static void main(String[] args)`?

Comment: yes exactly.I am talking about that values

Comment: Do you realise that there's a high chance that the mapper is running on a totally different JVM to the one that is running main?

Comment: but is there a way to access them? Or if such a condition arises what is the better solution to refer args

Comment: You'll either need to pass the parameter in the mapper arguments, or you'll need to distribute the value as @vefthym has said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Args[] is the input parameter of the main function of the Driver class. The only way to access this parameter is from within the Driver (the scope of this parameter is only the main function). So, if you want to pass these to the mapper, you will need to pass them as parameters (e.g. add this information to the Distributed Cache and get it from the configuration of the mappers).

If you simply want to pass some parameters, check [this article](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/11/passing-parameters-to-mappers-and.html), and replace "123" with args[2], or whatever arg you are interested in.

If you want to pass a whole file for processing, do the following:

Example:

main method in the Driver class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ... 
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));     
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
    ...
    try {
        DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[2]), conf);          
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    ....
}
```

In the Mapper, before the map() method, define the configure method (I am using hadoop 1.2.0):

```
Set<String> lines;
public void configure(JobConf job){
    lines = new HashSet<>();

    BufferedReader SW;
    try {
        localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);      
        SW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(localFiles[0].toString()));
        lines.add(SW.readLine());            
        SW.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }       
}
```

For more information on how to use the Distributed Cache, see the API:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vefthym.can u show me a small example

Comment: I am glad that I helped. I am not aware of any other alternative.